# API Gateway with EC2 Instance hosted API Integration

Tags: .net-core, iis, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I am new to AWS I have hosted my API on EC2 Instance. Imported my API swagger file to Gateway.
Now I want to call my EC2 instance API from API gateway how to integrate? should I choose integration type as HTTP, If yes then for each endpoint I have to map it manually in EndPoint section
or should I integrate it with my EC2 instance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For similar setup I've used the following chain:
VPCLink -> NLB -> Target Group ->EC2 instance.
If you choose HTTP your instance should have public ip or your instance should be behind load balancer with public ip.
With VPC link you can point to private subnet load balancer and instance that has only private ip, so VPCLink solution is more secure than HTTP, it doesn't allow to attack your resources directly by bypassing the APIGW.